# Connected sets with large boundary in a multigraph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected, undirected graph. Define the boundary $\partial S$ of a set $S\subset V$ to be the set of all $v\notin S$ joined to $S$ by an edge, i.e.
$$\partial S = \{v\not \in S: \exists v'\in S s.t. {v,v'}\in E\}.$$
We know that, if there are at least $n$ vertices of degree $\geq 3$ in $G$, then there is a set $S\subset V$ such that the subgraph $G|_{S}$ is connected and $\partial S$ has $\geq n/4+2$ elements.

(Proof: construct a spanning tree with $\geq n/4+2$ leaves, as per [Spanning trees: the last darn $1/4$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373733/spanning-trees-the-last-darn-1-4) . Then take $S$ to be the set of internal nodes. Thanks to F. Petrov ([Existence of connected component with large boundary?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362168/existence-of-connected-component-with-large-boundary)).)

Now draw some arrows between adjacent vertices of $G$ - i.e., define a directed multigraph $G'=(V,E')$ with the same set of vertices $V$ as $G$, and such that, if $(v,w)$ is an edge of $G'$, then $\{v,w\}$ is an edge of $G$. Assume that $G'$ is strongly connected. (If it helps, assume as well that the out-degree of every vertex equals its in-degree.)  Define the edge out-boundary $\vec{\partial} S$ of a set $S\subset V$ to be the set of arrows coming out of it. It is not hard to prove (using the above) that there is a set $S'\subset V$ such that $G|_{S'}$ is connected and $\vec{\partial} S$ has $\geq (n/4+2)/3$ elements. (In fact, for that, we do not need to assume that $G'$ is strongly connected - we only need to assume that the in-degree of every vertex is positive, together with the assumptions on $G$.)

Can we obtain something stronger, with the right assumptions? Say the number $N$ of arrows coming in and out of vertices that have degree $\geq 3$ in $G$ is quite large - much larger than $n$. Can one really not do better than $\geq (n/4+2)/3$?

Comment: Is there any relation between two graphs?

Comment: @Fedor_Petrov - ah, I should have made it clear - if $(v,w)$ is an arrow (edge of $G'$), then $\{v,w\}$ is an edge of $G$.

Comment: The question reduces to the following one: given a subset $V'\subset V$ of $m$ vertices of degree $\geq 3$, can we show that there is a set $S$ such that $G|_S$ is connected and $\partial S$ has $\geq \delta m$ elements ($\delta>0$ fixed) in $V'$? Proof of reduction: Let $V'$ be the set of vertices whose in-degree is at least half the average. Let $S$ be as just stated. Then define your new set $S$ to be that $S$, plus half the vertices not in $S$, taken randomly. (This seems to give $\delta = 1/32$; tweak to get a larger $\delta$.)

Comment: I think that should be an equivalence, at least if we drop the condition that the out-degree of every vertex equal its in-degree.

Comment: We could then continue the discussion in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408974/connected-sets-with-a-large-boundary-in-a-privileged-set